# Angular5 - @HostBinding instead of :host

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular2-hostbinding

I read that its better to use @HostBinding instead of :host. So i think about change my component.ts

```
@Component({
    host: {
        'class': 'cover',
        '[class.uploading]': 'uploadProgress > 0',
    }
})
```

This works fine, but when i change it to:

```
export class Cover {
    @HostBinding('class') classes = 'mark6-cover';
    @HostBinding('[class.uploading]') uploadProgress > 0;

    @Input() uploadProgress = null;
}
```

i get errors and nothing works. What i did wrong here? And how can i make the variable uploadProgress to a observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterpart to `'[class.uploading]': 'uploadProgress > 0'` would be:

```
@HostBinding('class.uploading')
@Input() 
uploadProgress = null;
```

`uploadProgress` input can be set asynchronously from observable subscription or elsewhere.

`uploading` class will be triggered for truthy `uploadProgress`, which is likely the expected behaviour.

In case the condition is different (e.g. input value can be negative, while a class should be triggered for positive values only), extra property can be added:

```
@Input() 
uploadProgress = null;

@HostBinding('class.uploading')
get isUploading() {
  return this.uploadProgress > 0;
}
```

If the condition is complex, it's preferable for a component to have `OnPush` change detection strategy.

Comment: Thanks, but this overwrite the @Input() uploadProgress = null; And why i cant set Operators like > there? i tryed now !== null but this also dont work on this place... i need to set the class only if there is any activity on uploadProgress... And i need to remove it again when the progress is done. Can it be that this is simply not possible with @HostBinding?

Comment: Sure, @Input is needed there too. I added some explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: I thank you so much, but i cant make it work. i tryed with your bottom code example, but the class uploading is still missing when i add a dummy value from outside (like 33). And i use allready changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: Thanks, now it works, i dont know why it yesterday dont. Maybe to tired ;) So you can confirm that @HostBinding is more dynamic than :host?

Comment: Glad you solved it. It's not more dynamic, it's more flexible. `host` is limited to expression string.

Comment: Ah i see: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-06-03 In some cases i dont need any big logic behind that var that i input from outside, but the docs says "be consistent in your choice." So you think its better when i use now everywhere @HostBinding and remove from all my files the :host? (to be consistent)

Comment: That's a matter of taste. I always use HostBinding, it's more expressive. You can also inherit it in child classes, IIRC.